# future.then block skipped inside function of return type integer causes to return null

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

I have stumbled upon a weird problem.

The following function gets a Firestore document and returns it so other functions can access it's data

```
Future getCountRequests() async {
  try{
    return await _countReference.document('Requests').get();
  } catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

And this is the function in question that uses it's data.

```
int _countRequest() {
  int toReturn;

  CounterService().getCountRequests().then(
    (doc) {
      //print('Item in question: $doc, information from document ${doc.data}'); 
      //this line prints correctly Instance of DocumentReference and {"amount" : 6}
      toReturn = doc.data['amount'];
    }
  );
  return toReturn;
}
```

When I run the code, I get an error message on my screen which states that the `AnimatedList` I am using receives null from the `_countRequest()` function.

Putting a break on this line has helped me understand that this block gets skipped completely

```
CounterService().getCountRequests().then( ...
```

However when I put a break on this line, it shows that the code inside the block works and that the document is indeed received through the `getCountRequests()` function.

```
toReturn = doc.data['amount'];
```

My question is, what causes the `.then` block to be skipped causing the function to return null?

Comment: You should add `await` before a future function to be fetched.

Comment: See these guidelines [1] for an explanation of "await" along some examples.
[1] https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await

Comment: Yes, I visited these pages. To my understanding from several other posts, the 'then' function was supposed to make it possible to get a value from an async function and make it usable in a sync function. This is what I attempted here, so that makes me wonder what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `then()` method gets called *after* you return from your `_countRequest` method, thats why you get `null` since `toReturn` is not set to any value in its declaration

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I will try your solution tomorrow and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Just to add to people comments. The .then function is not being skipped but because of the asynchronous nature of Futures the _countRequest function is not waiting for .then to execute or finish executing. You should wait for the Future to complete as the others are suggesting

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do cannot work.

You are trying to return the result of an asynchronous computation from a synchronous function. There is no way to make that work. 
An asynchronous computation will always complete *later*, and a synchronous function always returns *now*, so the result of the computation cannot be returned now.

The `then` call is what makes the operation asynchronous. It passes a callback to a future, but the only thing you are guaranteed about when that callback is called is that it is definitely *not* immediately. The `then` call returns immediately, returning a future which will be completed when the callback has been called, and your code returns the current value of `toReturn`, which is still `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured that doing this asynchronously with a `FutureBuilder` wouldn't work at all, or with my current skillset I just can't figure out how to make it work. So I decided to convert to a `StreamBuilder` which uses a `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` gotten from the following function.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> findAllRequests() {
  try{
    return accountRequestCollection.snapshots();
  } catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```

and built the `AnimatedList` into the `StreamBuilder` like so.

```
class Request extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RequestState createState() => _RequestState();
}

class _RequestState extends State<Request> {

  final AdministrationService _administrationService = AdministrationService();
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Account Requests'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _administrationService.findAllRequests(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Loading();
            default: if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.hasError}');
            } else {
              return AnimatedList(
                key: _globalKey,
                initialItemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, Animation animation) {
                  return _buildItem(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['email'], animation);
                }
              );    
            }
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(String item, Animation animation) {
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: animation,
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            item,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It results into this page.
[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2eNR.png). 
I hope that this solution can help others with similar problems, though I am not sure how costly this could get when it comes to firestore read/writes considering this is just a proof of concept product.